# How do I bind a SwiftUI element to a value in a Dictionary?

Tags: swiftui

I have a dictionary that contains various values I want to "filter" by. So I'm doing something like this

```
struct ExampleView : View {

    @EnvironmentObject var externalData : ExternalData

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(externalData.filters) { (v : (String, Bool)) in
                Toggle(isOn: $externalData.filters[v.0], label: {
                    Text("\(v.0)")
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

final class ExternalData : BindableObject {

    let didChange = PassthroughSubject<ExternalData, Never>()

    init() {
        filters["Juniper"] = true
        filters["Beans"] = false
    }

    var filters : Dictionary<String, Bool> = [:] {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(self)
        }
    }
}
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39624690/xcode-bind-textfield-to-element-of-a-swift-dictionary) seems related, but putting dynamic didn't seem to help and I wasn't able to figure out how to do that NSObject inheritance thing in this case. Right now, this code as is gives me this error:

```
Cannot subscript a value of type 'Binding<[String : Bool]>' with an argument of type 'String'
```

But trying to move the $ around or use paren in various ways doesn't seem to help. How can I bind the toggles to the values in my dictionary? I could just make manual toggles for each value, but that makes fragile code since (among other reasons) the potential filter values are based on a dataset that might have new values at some point.

I'm aware that I should really sort the keys (in some way) before iterating over them so the ordering is consistent, but that clutters this example so I left that code out.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I managed to make is work by using a custom binding for each filter.

```swift
final class ExternalData: BindableObject {
    let didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    var filters: Dictionary<String, Bool> = [:] {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(())
        }
    }

    init() {
        filters["Juniper"] = true
        filters["Beans"] = false
    }

    var keys: [String] {
        return Array(filters.keys)
    }

    func binding(for key: String) -> Binding<Bool> {
        return Binding(getValue: {
            return self.filters[key] ?? false
        }, setValue: {
            self.filters[key] = $0
        })
    }
}
```

The `keys` property list the `filters` keys as `String` so that it can be displayed (using `ForEach(externalData.keys)`)

The `binding(for:)` method, create a custom `Binding` for the given key. This binding is given to the `Toggle` to read/write the current value in the wrapped dictionary.

The view code:

```swift
struct ExampleView : View {

    @EnvironmentObject var externalData : ExternalData

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(externalData.keys) { key in
                Toggle(isOn: self.externalData.binding(for: key)) {
                    Text(key)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting an error at the `Text(key)` line in my view of `Type of Expression is ambiguious without more context`, does your code compile for you?

Comment: Figured it out, I need to do `ForEach(externalData.keys.identifiedby(\.self))` and then it works, thanks :)

Comment: This is a great solution! Thank you so much!

Comment: I am trying to use this for a DisclosureGroup but the group does not expand when clicked 'DisclosureGroup(isExpanded: self.categoriesShowing.binding(for: asset.category)) {...}'.  However if the parent group is collapsed and expanded then the group does expand correctly - so I think SwiftUI is not picking up the model change resulting from clicking the expand button.  Any suggestions?

Comment: This would be even more awesome if the Binding was generic. For now I have only been able to sort of do that by Re-binding