# How to use Dictionary as @Binding var in SwiftUI

Tags: binding, swiftui

I will need to display a collapsed menu in SwiftUI, it is possible to pass one single bool value as binding var to subviews but got stuck when trying to pass that value from a dictionary.

see code below:

```
struct MenuView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var data: APIData
    @State var menuCollapsed:[String: Bool] = [:]
    @State var isMenuCollapsed = false;

// I am able to pass self.$isMenuCollapsed but self.$menuCollapsed[menuItem.name], why?

var body: some View {

            if data.isMenuSynced {
                List() {
                    ForEach((data.menuList?.content)!, id: \.name) { menuItem in
                        TopMenuRow(dataSource: menuItem, isCollapsed: self.$isMenuCollapsed)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                if menuItem.isExtendable() {
                                    let isCollapsed = self.menuCollapsed[menuItem.name]
                                    self.menuCollapsed.updateValue(!(isCollapsed ?? false), forKey: menuItem.name)
                                } else {
                                    print("Go to link:\(menuItem.url)")
                                }

                            }
                    }
                }
            }else {
                Text("Loading...")
            }
        }

}
```

in ChildMenu Row:

```
struct TopMenuRow: View {
    var dataSource: MenuItemData
    @Binding var isCollapsed: Bool

    var body: some View {
        ChildView(menuItemData)
            if self.isCollapsed {
                //display List of child data etc
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I use only one single bool as the binding var, the code is running ok, however, if I would like to use a dictionary to store each status of the array, it has the error of something else, see image blow:
[image]

if I use the line above, it's fine.

Any idea of how can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Dictionary is not a RandomAccessCollection, so not supported in ForEach and Binding, use instead view model with Array of MenuItem struct containing title & selected (as I understood) properties. Don't hit into the wall - think different. =)

Comment: you can create a bindable dictionary https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56978746/how-do-i-bind-a-swiftui-element-to-a-value-in-a-dictionary

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How to use dictionary as a storage of mutable values with State property wrapper?

As mentioned by Asperi, ForEach requires that source of data conforms to RandomAccessCollection. **This requirements doesn't apply to State property wrapper!**

Let see one of the possible approaches in the next snippet (copy - paste - run)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var dict = ["alfa":false, "beta":true, "gamma":false]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(Array(dict.keys), id: \.self) { (key) in
                HStack {
                    Text(key)
                    Spacer()
                    Text(self.dict[key]?.description ?? "false").onTapGesture {
                        let v = self.dict[key] ?? false
                        self.dict[key] = !v
                    }.foregroundColor(self.dict[key] ?? false ? Color.red: Color.green)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

with the following result

[image]